# Convert typedef struct from C to Pascal

Tags: c, struct, typedef, pascal

I'm trying to convert a C-Header to pascal, but I'm struggling with the following line:

```
typedef struct GLFWwindow GLFWwindow;
```

Since I'm not very good at C I can't even figure out what this statement means. Therefor I'm also unable to translate it.

Is it some kind of anonymous structure or maybe a handle? In the subsequent code it's usually referred to as follows:

```
typedef void (* GLFWwindowposfun)(GLFWwindow*,int,int);
```

The thing which confuses me the most is, that the structure is not defined anywhere (it has no member?!). I assume the answer is incredibly simple but nevertheless I hope someone will help me :)

Comment: That's a forward declaration then. Hard to tell without more code.

Comment: The complete source code can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/files/glfw/3.0.3/glfw-3.0.3.zip/download
Maybe I was just blind, but I could not find any following definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik yes, it is a forward define, making the struct opague, but the final struct should be declared before use in the implementation.

This construct has no direct equivalent in Pascal, best replaced by a single "pointer" or a pointer to an empty record.

The second construct is a procedure type declaration

```
type
   PGLFWWindow = ^GLFWWindow;  // pointer types need explicit declaration 
                                           // in most modern pascals
   TGLFWwindowposfun = Procedure (param1:PGLFFwindowposfun; 
                                             param2,param3:integer);cdecl;
```

Note

1. prefix "P", "T", delphi style, since all identifiers share one namespace base classes of identifiers are separate by hungarian prefix notation (P=pointer, T=type etc).
   The GLFWindow type is better also prefix with T, for consistency.
2. The integer type is usually the same as C, but e.g. in the default mode [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org) integer is 16-bit (for TP compatibility). If you use FPC, ctypes.cint is the best fit for C's integer.
3. Since the default Pascal calling convention is usually not the same as C's on x86, I applied a calling convention modifier cdecl which means "C calling convention".

**addendum** to be clear, GLFWINDOW would be an empty record (GLWINDOW= record end;), not a pointer to an empty record.